# Ansible extract shell output using awk

Tags: shell, module, ansible, ansible-template

```
---
- name: Data Collection
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: List all users
      shell: "cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'"
      register: users
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/users.csv
        create: yes
        line: "The {{ inventory_hostname}}, {{ users.stdout }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Doesn't give the intended output as I'm getting syntax error for using awk / grep in shell module. Kindly refer the intended output.

```
172.17.254.201, root
172.17.254.201, bin
172.17.254.201, nobody
172.17.254.201, test1
172.17.254.201, test2
172.17.254.202, root
172.17.254.202, bin
172.17.254.202, nobody
172.17.254.202, test1
172.17.254.202, test2
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain the error is related to the `shell` task? I was able to run it without errors.

One issue with the provided example is that `lineinfile` is only used once (i.e. only a single line will be updated). We can solve this issue by utilizing Ansible `loop`.

```
---
- name: Data Collection
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: List all users
      shell: "cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'"
      register: users
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/users.csv
        create: yes
        line: "{{ inventory_hostname}}, {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users.stdout_lines }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

If you're using DNS records in the inventory file but want IP addresses in the `.csv` file, then you'll want to replace `inventory_hostname` with a `host_vars` lookup (likely) for `hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']`.

If not, the above example should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the Ansible getent module for this:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html&ved=2ahUKEwipvfiwo_btAhVjShUIHVkXBpQQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw3TsoMUpdCHNOdEqU6VDLGk

This will help you avoid the need for using awk.